# Castings en objetos de clases derivadas

Tags: java, poo, clase, estructuras-de-datos, herencia

Tengo una pregunta sobre la solución del siguiente ejercicio; en la clase main, cuando llamo los métodos fuerza() o telequinesis() (que están en las clases derivadas), tengo que hacer varios castings en un vector que declare del tipo de la clase padre para que pueda llamar a esos métodos correctamente, y mi pregunta es: Existe alguna otra manera de llevar a cabo lo que pide el programa?

**Ejercicio:**
Generar un programa en Java que modele, herencia múltiple y polimorfismo la superclase Metahumano. De dicha clase se derivarán Héroe y Villano.
Cada uno de ellos, ya sea héroe o villano, puede tener al menos dos de los siguientes poderes: volar, velocidad, fuerza, debilidad, oír, telequinesis, telepatía; más al menos un poder propio (único).
Modelar al menos 2 héroes y 2 villanos, los cuales lucharán valiéndose de sus poderes.
El usuario introducirá el nombre del héroe o villano del que desee saber cuáles son sus poderes ya sea para salvar o destruir.

```
interface PoderParticular
{
String telequinesis();
String telepatia();
}

class Metahumano  
{                                                    

String velocidad()
{
   return "Tiene velocidad";
}

String debilidad()
{
   return "Tiene debilidad";
}
String oir()
{
   return "Tiene audicion";
}
}

class Heroe extends Metahumano implements PoderParticular
{ 
public String telepatia(){return "";} 
String velocidad()
{
   return "Tiene mucha velocidad";
}
String fuerza()
{
   return "Tiene mucha fuerza";
} 
public String telequinesis()
{
   return ":-)";
}
}

class Villano extends Metahumano implements PoderParticular
{ public String telequinesis(){return "";}

public String telepatia()
{
return "Tiene nivel 1 en telepatia";  
}
String volar()
{
   return "Puede volar muy alto"; 
}  
String debilidad()
{
   return "Tiene poca debilidad";
}
}

public class EjercicioClase22ago {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in); 

   Metahumano x[]=new Metahumano[4];
                   x[0]=new Heroe();
                   x[1]=new Villano();

 System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del heroe o del villano del 
 que desee saber cuales son sus superpoderes ya sea para salvar o 
 destruir");
       String personaje=leer.next();

    int n=personaje.compareTo("batman");
    int k= personaje.compareTo("superman");
    int l=personaje.compareTo("wason");
    int m= personaje.compareTo("duende");

    if (n==0 || k==0)
         System.out.println(x[0].velocidad()+" "+((Heroe)x[0]).fuerza()+" "+((PoderParticular)x[0]).telequinesis());
     else
         if(l==0|| m==0)
         System.out.println(((PoderParticular)x[1]).telepatia()+" "+((Villano)x[1]).volar()+" "+x[1].debilidad());
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás confundiendo los super poderes con los métodos de las interfaces o clases. Cuando se trata de las acciones, lo mejor es que el super poder sea una interfaz y cada poder sea una implementación de dicha interfaz.  Así, luego puedes hacer que los meta humanos tengan dos poderes, los cuales serán dinámicos y dependerán de lo que necesites.

Aquí un ejemplo.

```
public interface Superpoder {
    void usar();
}

public class Vuelo implements Superpoder {
    @Override
    public void usar() {
        System.out.println("Comienzo a volar");
    }
}

public class Fuerza implements Superpoder {
    @Override
    public void usar() {
        System.out.println("No soy gordo, soy fuertecito");
    }
}

//más implementaciones

public abstract class Metahumano {

    //estos poderes son dinámicos
    private Superpoder poder1;
    private Superpoder poder2;
}

public class Heroe extends Villano {
    //...
}

//luego de definir las interfaces y clases, así los puedes enlazar

public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Heroe heroe = new Heroe();
    heroe.setPoder1(new Vuelo());
    heroe.setPoder2(new Fuerza());
    heroe.getPoder1().usar();
    heroe.getPoder2().usar();
}
```

Salida:

```
Comienzo a volar
No soy gordo, soy fuertecito
```

Comment: hmm entonces mi ejercicio está mal resuelto?

Comment: Sí. Esta alternativa brinda más flexibilidad en el diseño de las clases y muestra más el poder del polimorfismo en Java. De la forma que tienes ahora, es complicado asignar los poderes de manera aleatoria a cada metahumano.

Comment: en donde aplicaste polimorfismo? Yo sabia que solo se puede aplicar en algo como esto:`Metahumano a=new Villano();` o new Heroe().

Comment: La interfaz `Superpoder` y las clases que lo implementan. Eso es polimofismo.

Comment: aah si? eso no me lo dijeron.. :( .Pero bueno, y porque mencionas que los poderes se deben de asignar de manera aleatoria a cada metahumano? eso no lo pide el ejercicio, o acaso estoy entendiendo mal el ejercicio?

Comment: Bueno, leyendo lo que dice tu ejercicio, específicamente esta parte: "Cada uno de ellos, ya sea héroe o villano, puede tener al menos dos de los siguientes poderes: (poderes...)". Esto significa que un `Heroe` o `Villano` (clases) pueden tener 2 poderes de manera aleatoria. Cuando tienes esta situación, significa que la acción debe aplicarse de manera dinámica. ¿Cómo consigues este dinamismo? Con polimorfismo y una técnica muy importante llamada composición. Se recomienda mucho usar composición sobre herencia.

Comment: ooh, ok entonces tendre que volver a hacerlo, ahora tomando en cuenta lo que me has dicho. Fijate que me sorprende bastante lo que dices porque mi profesor ya me habia revisado este ejercicio, y me dijo que estaba **bien** wow, porque me habra dicho eso?? si esta mal

Comment: Hay profesores que no saben lo que enseñan o simplemente enseñan mal. No es la primera vez que encuentro una persona cuy@ profesor@ explica las cosas incompletas o con problemas =\

Answer (score 1):

Los castings va muy relacionado con la herencia.

Si un metahumano ES SIEMPRE UN humano, entonces la clase metahumano hereda de la clase humano.

A su vez, si necesitas que un metahumano pase por humano para poder hacer algo, se puede hacer un casting, y por eso superman puede ser un periodista, haciendo un upcasting.

```
Humano Clark=(Humano)superman;
```

Una variable objeto de una superclase puede almacenar siempre un objeto de esa misma superclase o de cualquiera de sus subclases. Por la ley de la herencia "ES SIEMPRE UN".